# Using Flyway command-line to pass runtime arguments into Java migration classes

Tags: java, database, command-line, migration, flyway

I'm using Flyway's command-line tool to execute SQL and Java migrations. 
What I'm trying to do is pass runtime arguments from the command line and access those runtime arguments in my Java migration classes.

An example being: I want to load a specific file into my java migration class and this file name needs to be passed as a runtime argument from the command line and be accessible 
via the java migration class.  Would this be possible? Is there a better solution to this problem?

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: What is your goal? What should the migration class do with the file?

Comment: The migration class would take data to be inserted into a blob column.

Comment: I've managed to do this using flyway.cmd migrate -Dflyway.environment=dev, but in order to get this property in Java, I have to do System.getProperty("sun.java.command"), which outputs com.googlecode.flyway.commandline.Main migrate -Dflyway.environment=dev... ouch! Does anyone know how I can get just the info I need (flyway.environment=dev)?